# Why after retainAll() the list comes to be null although it should has elements in it?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Now I can get list A, list B. And I want to get a new list which is A-(intersection of A and B). But when I get the intersection, it is [].

```
        List<Map<String,String>> userDevices = clientdeviceService.getUserDevice(userId);
        List<String> selectedDevices = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(devices));//selectedDevices  is------[stress0012,stress0014,]
        List<String> originalDevices = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> originalDevicesRetain = new ArrayList<String>();//copy for operating
        for(Map<String,String> originalDevId : userDevices){
            originalDevices.add(originalDevId.get("DEVID"));
        }
        originalDevicesRetain.addAll(originalDevices);
        originalDevicesRetain.retainAll(selectedDevices);
        //originalDevicesRetain now is [],and it return false.
        originalDevices.removeAll(originalDevicesRetain);
        if(!originalDevices.isEmpty()){

        }
```

Why originalDevices is [] has no elements in it?

Comment: An empty list is not the same as null.

Comment: And it's probably because the `originalDevicesRetain` has none of the `selectedDevices`; therefore, there's nothing to retain.